The solution's existance condition for homogeneous linear second order partial derivative equation.
My problem originally comes from a coupled SDE problem. Suppose that we have a coupled SDE problem with all the parameters $F_{11}, F_{12}, F_{21}, F_{22}, \sigma_1, \sigma_2$ to be constants:
$$
\begin{align*}
& d u_1 = (F_{11}u_1 + F_{12}u_2)d t + \sigma_1 d W_1\\
& d u_2 = (F_{21}u_1 + F_{22}u_2)d t + \sigma_2 d W_2
\end{align*}
$$
where $W_1$ and $W_2$ are independent white noise sources, i.e. independently following $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. There is a HW problem telling me to find the conditions containing only $F_{11}, F_{12}, F_{21}, F_{22}$, which can make equilibrium distribution (stationary distribution w.r.t. $u_1$ and $u_2$, i.e. $p(u_1, u_2)$) of the system exist.
After I derived the Fokker-Planck's equation, I have the following partial derivative equation:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = & -[\frac{\partial (F_{11}u_1p + F_{12}u_2p)}{\partial u_1} + \frac{\partial (F_{21}u_1p + F_{22}u_2p)}{\partial u_2}] + \frac{1}{2}(\sigma_1^2 \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial u_1^2} + \sigma_2^2 \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial u_2^2})\\
=& \frac{1}{2}(\sigma_1^2 \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial u_1^2} + \sigma_2^2 \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial u_2^2}) - [(F_{11}u_1 + F_{12}u_2) \frac{\partial p}{\partial u_1} + (F_{21}u_1 + F_{22}u_2) \frac{\partial p}{\partial u_2}] \\
&- (F_{11} + F_{22})p
\end{align*}
$$
where $p := p(u_1, u_2, t)$ is the distribution w.r.t. variables $u_1, u_2$ and time $t$.
Since we want to find the stationary distribution, then just set $\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = 0$ and only consider $p$ to be the distribution w.r.t. $u_1$ and $u_2$. Then, the rest is a homogeneous linear second-order partial derivative equation. However, I am not familiar with the existance condition for this equation's solution. Could anyone help me out? Or maybe I am not on the right track?
